# How do I create the Time dimension and derived attribute in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I currently have 3 dimension tables :

**Warehouse Name** :  `[sabyawarehouse].[dbo]`

- **DimProd** : [productkey],[product-id],[prod-name],[unit-cost],[manufacturer-name]
- **DimCust** : [customerkey],[customer#],[address],[telephone#]
- **DimOrder** : [order-key], order#

How do I create `DimTime` which has attributes Timekey, date and week?

I am using SSIS. I am very confused, please help!

Comment: Shall be highly obliged if someone replies!

Answer (score 0):

A standard date dimension (which would give you what you need, and more!) can be created in various different ways- there are freely shared scripts available by googling something like "date dimension creation" to do the job which you could use directly, or learn from to make your own if your needs differ (or if this is an academic/learning question).

In SSIS for example, you can make a package that contains a C# script that loops through days and inserts appropriate roles. Similar scripts are available as T-SQL scripts, or there are Excel based solutions.